# matplotlibで50色の色分けはできますか？

Tags: python3, matplotlib

matplotlibでcmap　tab20などで20色の色分けはできるのですが、
50色の色分けをしたいのですが、どなたかご存じの方いらっしゃいますか？

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも？ [matplotlibで色をたくさん使う](https://blog.imind.jp/entry/2019/05/10/031150) あるいはこれとか？ [How to set a colormap which can give me over 20 distinct colors in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37299142/9014308)

Comment: 2番目のものを使ってみます。

Comment: エラーがだらだら出ました。

Comment: tab50みたいなものはないのでしょうか？実装も含めて教えてください。

Comment: この記事とか応用すれば何とかなるかも。[matplotlibでcolor cycleのN番目の色を指定するいくつかの方法](https://qiita.com/skotaro/items/5c9893d186ccd31f459d), あと色選択にほぼ関係は無いけどmatplotlibの解説記事。[matplotlibのめっちゃまとめ](https://qiita.com/nkay/items/d1eb91e33b9d6469ef51)

Comment: N番目の色を指定するいくつかの方法でうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 公開して支障の無い範囲で適用対象の目的とか結果を自己回答してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

GAによる最適化で最適順にグラフを使ってジオメトリを表すのに使う予定です。
多数の候補を例示できました。